# Pair Sum problem - c# code doesn't produce expected output-- please assist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
   public static int FindMaxNumForMaxSum(int[] nums, int k)
    {
        int retVal = 0;
        int N = nums.Length;
        var counter = 1;
        var map = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (nums[i] == retVal)
            {
                counter++;
                continue;
            }
            var complement = k - nums[i];
            retVal = complement;
            if (nums[i] == complement)
            {
                if (!map.ContainsKey(complement))
                {
                    map.Add(complement, counter);
                }
                else
                {
                    map[complement] = counter++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                map.Add(complement, counter);
            }

        }
        return counter;
    }
```

Above is my code.
Problem description below:
Given a list of n integers arr[0..(n-1)], determine the number of different pairs of elements within it which sum to k.
If an integer appears in the list multiple times, each copy is considered to be different; that is, two pairs are considered different if one pair includes at least one array index which the other doesn't, even if they include the same values.
The above solution doesn't see to produce expected output and also there is a problem of adding duplicate keys in a dictionary.

```
Example 1
n = 5
k = 6
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3]
output = 2
The valid pairs are 2+4 and 3+3.
Example 2
n = 5
k = 6
arr = [1, 5, 3, 3, 3]
output = 4
Example 3
arr = [2, 3, 6, 7, 4, 5, 1]
output = 3
```

Comment: `var complement = k = nums[i];` are you sure you wish to modify `k` inside the method? `map.TryGetValue` will check if the element exists, there's no point checking `map.ContainsKey` in every other code path for the same key, the answer will not have changed. `map[complement] += 1` I don't think that will do what you expect, try `map[complement] = val+1`.

Comment: `var complement = k = nums[i];` should be `var complement = k - nums[i];` please debug your code and try to understand the logic of your code. Because that's what we also ned to do to figure what's the issue..

Comment: I think I figured out, thanks for all the suggestions, I've updated my code above.